# Shell command doesn't function, but echo'ing the command and manually running it works?

Tags: bash, shell, terraform

I'm trying to run the following lines of shell script:

```
var_files=$(var_file_selector)
echo ${var_files}
terraform apply ${var_files} deploy/$1
```

Where var_files resolves to "deploy/vars/vars.tfvars".  When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
invalid value "\"deploy/vars/vars.tfvars\"" for flag -var-file: Error reading "deploy/vars/vars.tfvars": open "deploy/vars/vars.tfvars": no such file or directory
```

However if I echo out the whole command:

```
echo terraform apply ${var_files} deploy/$1
```

I get:

```
terraform apply -var-file="deploy/vars/vars.tfvars" deploy/cluster
```

Which I can run manually from the terminal (in the same working directory that I'm running the script from) and it works just fine.  What am I not understanding here?

Comment: Do you not want -var-file=deploy/vars/vars.tfvars without the quotes?

Comment: What does `var_file_selector` do and is there a reason you're not just using `terraform.tfvars` and/or `*.auto.tfvars` files?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Yes this works without the quotes.  Not sure why it works with them when I manually put the command into the terminal though?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR var_file_selector just loops over *.tfvars in my vars file dir, and just give each one a '--var-file=...' tag.  I didn't know you could just have a specifier as the passed var file.

Comment: Maybe terraform adds the quotes to the value passed as argument, and as you are alredy including them, they are treated as part of the string, this is why they are escaped in the log you provided:


    invalid value "\"deploy/vars/vars.tfvars\"" ....

Comment: `var_file_selector` appears to be adding quotes when it shouldn't (nor does it need to). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023462/1126841. There is a big difference between `x='"foo"'; echo $x` and `x=foo; echo "$x"`.

Comment: The shell parses quotes before expanding variables, so quotes *in* variables don't get parsed properly (by the time they're there, it's too late for them to work right). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-shell-syntax-in-arguments-passed-via-variables).