# How to string concatenate on bash and send it as json with curl?

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

This is what I am trying to get working:

```
body="\"\:warning\: \:exclamation\: Your pull request is not linked to any issue, please make the corresponding changes in the very first comments body by adding \'Fixes #issue-number\' or \'Resolves #issue-number\'. If your pull request isn\'t linked to any issue, ignore this comment\!\""
echo $body
json="'{\"body\": ${body} }'"
echo $json
statusCode=`curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' -H 'Authorization: token ****' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.github.com/repos/Ismoh/NoitaMP/issues/79/comments -d $json`
echo "statusCode="$statusCode
```

echo $body:

```
$ echo $body
"\:warning\: \:exclamation\: Your pull request is not linked to any issue, please make the corresponding changes in the very first comments body by adding \'Fixes #issue-number\' or \'Resolves #issue-number\'. If your pull request isn\'t linked to any issue, ignore this comment\!"
```

echo $json

```
$ echo $json
'{"body": "\:warning\: \:exclamation\: Your pull request is not linked to any issue, please make the corresponding changes in the very first comments body by adding \'Fixes #issue-number\' or \'Resolves #issue-number\'. If your pull request isn\'t linked to any issue, ignore this comment\!" }'
```

curl

```
$ curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' -H 'Authorization: token ****' -H 'Content-Type: application/json
' https://api.github.com/repos/Ismoh/NoitaMP/issues/79/comments -d $json
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue-comment"
}
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Your
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: pull
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: request
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: is
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: not
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: linked
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: to
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: any
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: issue,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: please
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: make
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: the
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: corresponding
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: changes
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: in
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: the
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: very
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: first
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: comments
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: body
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: by
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: adding
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \'Fixes
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: or
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \'Resolves
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: If
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: your
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: pull
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: request
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: isn\'t
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: linked
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: to
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: any
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: issue,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ignore
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: this
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: comment\!"
curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1:
}'
```

[GitHub API Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/comments#create-an-issue-comment) shows the json data as following:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/issues/ISSUE_NUMBER/comments \
  -d '{"body":"Me too"}'
```

Is anyone out there, who can tell me what I am doing wrong?

Is there a better way to escape string for json usage? I already tried out `jq -Rsa .`, but didn't work either.

Comment: Double-quote your variable references, e.g. `"$json"` instead of just `$json`. See ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion) (short answer: almost always).

Comment: Don't try to create JSON by hand with string operations. Use the `jq` utility.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I am going to try quoting! I already tried jq, but I still didnt understand it!

Comment: "$json" doesnt work. GitHubs response: Unable to parse JSON.

Comment: Shell scripting 101: `"$json"`, not `$json` to preserve whitespace in values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to build that JSON with jq:

```
body="\"\:warning\: \:exclamation\: Your pull request is not linked to any issue, please make the corresponding changes in the very first comments body by adding \'Fixes #issue-number\' or \'Resolves #issue-number\'. If your pull request isn\'t linked to any issue, ignore this comment\!\""
json="$(jq -n --arg body "$body" '{ $body }')"
# or: json=$(printf '%s\n' "$body" | jq -R '{ body: . }')
```

I doubt that all that escaping above is actually necessary – why escape a colon, an exclamation mark or a single quote? But it might be that the API expects these character quoted; I don't see why though, since it consumes JSON. Best bet is probably to get rid of all the backslashes above when assigning body (except the ones before `"`).

Here's how to correctly expand a variable which contains whitespace, for instance when using it as payload for a curl command (note the quotes around the variable). Variables should *always* be quoted, unless you know 110% what you are doing:

```
curl -X POST \
 -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
 -H 'Authorization: token ****' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 https://api.github.com/repos/Ismoh/NoitaMP/issues/79/comments \
 -d "$json"
```

Useful resources:

- [jq 1.6 Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/)
- [jq wiki](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki)
- [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ)
- [jq cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook)
- [Advanced topics](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Advanced-Topics)
- [A stream-oriented introduction to jq](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I escaped everything just because I am new to this and I was struggling. If you want me to do a favour, would it be possible to add a doc link to jq? Because I don't want to just copy paste stuff. I really want to learn!

Comment: @Ismoh added several useful links to the answer

Comment: Just for your info: line 3 in your example is working. line 2 isn't.

Comment: @Ismoh oh, thanks for the hint. Line 2 was missing `-n` (`--null-input`), because it doesn't read any JSON from stdin.