# how to format the result on several lines when using grep in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep, format, output

In several files, I would like to extract the lines (with their number)

- which contain the ClNonZ pattern
- and which have the value "real" as first attribute.

for a unitary file, I get the line feed respect.

but I have several files, so I make a "for" loop, and then the multiple occurrences of a file are presented without linefeed

Exemple :

```
$ cat foo1.txt
A TEST 0.959660297 0 0.021231423 -0.0073 -0.0031 MhZisp
B REAL 0.180467091 0.800424628 0 0.0566 0.0103 ClNonZ
C REAL 0.98089172 0 0 -0.0158 0.0124 MhNonZ
D TEST 0.704883227 0.265392781 0.010615711 -0.0087 -0.0092 MhZisp
E REAL 0.010615711 0.959660297 0.010615711 0.0476 0.0061 ClNonZ
F TEST 0.704883227 0.265392781 0.010458211 0.0865 0.0548 ClNonZ

$ cat foo2.txt
A TEST 0.715498938 0 0.265392781 -0.0013 -0.0309 Unkn
B REAL 0.927813163 0 0.053078556 -0.0051 -0.0636 MhZisp
C TEST 0.55626327 0.222929936 0.201698514 0.0053 -0.0438 MhZisp
D REAL 0.492569002 0.350318471 0.138004246 0.0485 0.0088 ClNonZ
E REAL 0.704883227 0.265392781 0.010615711 0.0476 0.0061 AbbbbZ
F REAL 0.180467091 0.800424628 0 0.0566    0.0103  ClNonZ
```

grep without loop : result ok for me,  with line break :

```
$  grep -n ClNonZ foo1.txt  | awk '$2 == "REAL" {print $0}'

2:B REAL 0.180467091 0.800424628 0 0.0566 0.0103 ClNonZ
5:E REAL 0.010615711 0.959660297 0.010615711 0.0476 0.0061 ClNonZ
```

grep in a for loop : bad presentation, line breaks have disappeared :

```
$  for file in `ls foo*` ; do line=`grep -n ClNonZ $file | awk '$2 == "REAL" {print $0}' `; if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then  echo $file ; echo $line ; echo " " ; fi ; done

foo1.txt
2:B REAL 0.180467091 0.800424628 0 0.0566 0.0103 ClNonZ 5:E REAL 0.010615711 0.959660297 0.010615711 0.0476 0.0061 ClNonZ
 
foo2.txt
4:D REAL 0.492569002 0.350318471 0.138004246 0.0485 0.0088 ClNonZ 6:F REAL 0.180467091 0.800424628 0 0.0566 0.0103 ClNonZ
```

I tried to used "while" instead of "for" (as explained in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 as suggested by @chepner)  without success.

would you have an idea that could help me, please ?

Comment: Btw: See: [Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs.](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2045) and [Bash Pitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1)

Comment: Question is misleading. `grep` and `for` loop are not the cause of the problem. The last step, you added a subshell to capture the output to a variable and then you use `echo` on that variable. That is the cause of the line breaks to disappear.

Comment: As the `bash` tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary problem here is that you didn't double-quote your variable references, especially in `echo $line` (should be `echo "$line"`). This often causes problems like this. See ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion) (short answer: almost always).

[Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this, and will also have some other good recommendations for your code. I recommended using it!

However, in this case, I'd be tempted to replace the entire bash+grep+awk thing, since awk can do it all itself:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {needheader=1}; ($0 ~ /ClNonZ/ && $2 == "REAL") {if (needheader) {print ""; print FILENAME; needheader=0}; print}' foo*.txt
```

Explanation:

1. `FNR==1 {needheader=1}` -- this triggers at the beginning of each file (`FNR` is the line number within the current file, so if it's 1 this is the beginning of a file) and sets a variable saying that if there's a match, the filename needs to be printed.
2. `($0 ~ /ClNonZ/ && $2 == "REAL")` -- if "ClNonZ" appears in the line, and the second field is "REAL", then do the following stuff in `{ }`. Note: do you actually want to search the entire line for "ClNonZ", or just the last field? If it's just the last field, use `$NF == "ClNonZ"`)
3. `if (needheader) {print ""; print FILENAME; needheader=0}` -- if this is the first match within this file, print a blank line and the filename, then clear the variable that says this stuff needs to be printed.
4. `print` -- ...and print the line. Note that `$0` is implicit here, and since this is still in the `{ }` from step 2, it only happens if the line matched.
5. `foo*.txt` -- just pass all the matching filenames to `awk` as arguments, and let it scan over all of them in a big batch.