# Store yaml file content in shell script variable and maintain yaml structure

Tags: bash, shell

I have one yaml file named file.yaml

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: dashboarding-route
spec:
  host: dashboarding-route.domain
  port:
    targetPort: 100
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: dashboarding
```

Then I run this command

```
template=$(cat "file.yaml" | sed "s/domain/$MYVARVALUE/g")
```

MYVARVALUE variable value can be anything.

after executing this I want value of template variable in same structure as a yaml file.
For Ex. when I do echo $template the out put I want is

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: dashboarding-route
spec:
  host: dashboarding-route.domain
  port:
    targetPort: 100
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: dashboarding
```

Can anyone please help me in this problem?

Comment: Doesn't quote i.e. `echo "$template"` output what you need?

Comment: See ["I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) and ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion) (short answer: almost always).

Answer (score 1):

## Solution1: "just use plain echo with double-quotes around the variable" -[Gordon Davidson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson)

```bash
$: MYVARVALUE=some-new-domain
$: template=$(cat "file.yaml" | sed "s/domain/$MYVARVALUE/g")
$: echo "$template"
```

Which gives the following `stdout`:

```bash
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: dashboarding-route
spec:
  host: dashboarding-route.some-new-domain
  port:
    targetPort: 100
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: dashboarding
```

## Solution2: use `printf` instead of `echo`

You could use `printf` instead of `echo` to preserve the `yaml` formatting, like so:

```bash
$: MYVARVALUE=some-new-domain
$: template=$(cat "file.yaml" | sed "s/domain/$MYVARVALUE/g")
$: printf '%s\n' "$template"
```

Which gives the following `stdout`:

```bash
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: dashboarding-route
spec:
  host: dashboarding-route.some-new-domain
  port:
    targetPort: 100
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: dashboarding
```

## Solution3: encode/decode `stdout` using `base64`

Another option to preserve formatting is to encode the data when storing/transmitting it, and then decode it when accessing/receiving it:

```bash
$: MYVARVALUE=some-new-domain
$: template=$(cat "file.yaml" | sed "s/domain/$MYVARVALUE/g" | base64 -w 0)
$: echo "$template" | base64 -d
```

Which also gives the following `stdout`:

```bash
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: dashboarding-route
spec:
  host: dashboarding-route.some-new-domain
  port:
    targetPort: 100
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: dashboarding
```

This last solution is particularly useful for moving formatting-sensitive data such as ssh-keys or hash-values between machines; **just be aware the this is not a substitute for encryption!**

Comment: `echo -e` is almost always a mistake. It's not portable (some versions just print "-e" in the output), and this case the only thing the `-e` option is going to do is to make `echo` try to interpret any backslashes in the data as escape sequences, possibly mangling the yaml as a result. `echo -n` is also unportable, and will give technically invalid output in this case. Just use plain `echo` with double-quotes around the variable. Also, in Solution2, you shouldn't put data in `printf`'s format string; use `printf '%s\n' "$template"` instead.

Comment: That's good to know about the issues with `echo -e`, thanks for the heads-up :)