# how to read value from log file which has json format values

Tags: bash, sh

I have log files which stores the output in json format (looks to be). but when i try to use jq method of reading the file its not working

command i used `echo $log | jq '.username'`

log file contains :

```
{u'username': u'tempname', u'command_log': u'logfilelocation', u'reporting': True}
```

I am trying to use

```
echo $log | jq '.command_log'
```

I want to read the command_log value and pass this to some other function.

Getting Error parse error: Invalid numeric literal

Comment: Why do you pass the file name (`$log`) to `jq`, instead of the content? Try `jq ... "$log"`.

Comment: That's not json; looks like maybe python syntax to me (maybe?). Also, never use `echo $var` -- you should (almost) always double-quote variable references, like `echo "$var"`. See ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion)

Comment: Getting the error jq: error: log/0 is not defined at <top-level>

Comment: With bash, herestrings are a useful way of avoiding `echo`ing a variable's contents: `command arg ... <<<"$foo"`

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not JSON, but Python's native data. You can use Python to dump it:

```py
$ python -c "log=$log; print(log['command_log'])"
```

Comment: This would generate syntax error unless $log is properly quoted.

Comment: I agree. However, by the look of it, `$log` looks like Python data, so it must be properly quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simple combination of `grep` and `cut` might do the job?

```
Field='username'
grep -o -e "\\<u'${Field}': u'[^']*'" INPUTFILE | cut -d "'" -f 4
```

Based on the following input (contents of INPUTFILE):

```
{u'username': u'tempname', u'command_log': u'logfilelocation', u'reporting': True}
```

it produces:

```
tempname
```

Tested under Debian 11 with GNU grep in POSIXLY_CORRECT mode.

Hope that helps.