# Executing bash commands with spaces

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am trying to learn and write Bash scripts. The problem I am facing is to execute a command with parameters including spaces stored in a variable.

Let me give you a small example. A simple script contains a single line to print the parameter passed:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
 
echo $1
```

If I run `./test.sh "Abcd Efgh"` from the bash shell, it successfully prints `Abcd Efgh`

But if I put the command in a variable `comm='./test.sh "Abcd Efgh"'` and then run `$comm`, it print `"Abcd`

Could you please help me to solve this so that I can print `Abcd Efgh` in the second case as well?
Thanks in advance.
-ADR

Comment: Escaping in bash will drive you batty.  Better to use `echo $*` in the script and skip the quoting.

Comment: Don't try to put commands in variables, it's an invitation to all sorts of problems and confusion (see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)). Variables are for storing *data* not executable code or shell syntax. Use functions for storing executable code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Using `$*` and skipping proper quoting is an open invitation to a  *different* bunch of problems. Quote properly, including putting double-quotes around variable references (see ["When should I double-quote a parameter expansion?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023461/when-should-i-double-quote-a-parameter-expansion)), and you almost always want `"$@"` instead of anything involving `$*`. BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting many common mistakes about things like this.